# Segmentation fault when calling lambda returns from high-order function in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functional-programming, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which trying to define procedures in CPS form.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


template <typename T> using Func = std::function<T>;
template <typename T> using Cont = Func<void (T &&)>;
template <typename T, typename U> using Proc = Func<void (T &&, Cont<U>)>;

template <typename T> struct RevProc;
template <typename T, typename U> struct RevProc<Proc<T, U>> {
  using ArgType = T;
  using RetType = U;
};

template <typename P1, typename P2> auto pipe(P1 proc1, P2 proc2)
  -> Proc<typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType, typename RevProc<P2>::RetType> {
  using T = typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType;
  using U = typename RevProc<P2>::ArgType;
  static_assert(is_same<U, typename RevProc<P1>::RetType>::value,
    "Mismatch procedure type.");
  using V = typename RevProc<P2>::RetType;
  return [&] (T &&t, Cont<V> pass) {
    proc1(move(t), [&] (U &&u) {
      proc2(move(u), pass);
    });
  };
}
template <typename P1, typename P2, typename... Ps> auto pipe(P1 proc1, P2 proc2, Ps ...procs)
  -> Proc<typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType, typename RevProc<decltype(pipe(proc2, procs...))>::RetType> {
  auto proc2s = pipe(proc2, procs...);
  return pipe(proc1, proc2s);
}

int main() {
  Func<void ()> var1;
  Cont<int> var2([] (int &&x) {});
  Proc<int, int> var3([] (int &&x, Cont<int> pass) {
    pass(x + 1);
  });
  auto var4 = pipe(var3, var3);
  var4(42, [] (int &&x) {
    cout << x << endl;
  });
  Proc<string, int> var5([] (string &&str, Cont<int> pass) {
    pass(str.length());
  });
  // auto var6 = pipe(var5, var5);
  Proc<int, int> var7 = pipe(var3, var3, var3);
  // var7(42, [] (int &&x) {
  //   cout << x << endl;
  // });
  auto var8 = pipe(var5, var3, var3);
  var8("something", [] (int &&x) {
    cout << x << endl;
  });

  return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment `var6` line, the compiler throw an error as expect. However, if either `var7` or `var8`'s calling is uncommented, then the code passes compilation but a random segmentation fault or bus error would be triggered at runtime. The code is safe during building the lambda but crashing when applying them.

Thanks for pointing out my faulty.

---

It may be useful to complement that it runs well if I modify the code to

```
var7 = pipe(var3, pipe(var3, var3));
```

So as `var8`.

---

I tried randomly and it fixed, to my surprise. I just keep the first declaration and modify the second by copying the first:

```
template <typename P1, typename P2, typename... Ps> constexpr auto pipe(P1 proc1, P2 proc2, Ps ...procs)
  -> Proc<typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType, typename RevProc<decltype(pipe(proc2, procs...))>::RetType> {
  using T = typename RevProc<P1>::ArgType;
  using U = typename RevProc<P2>::ArgType;
  static_assert(is_same<U, typename RevProc<P1>::RetType>::value,
    "Mismatch procedure type.");
  using V = typename RevProc<P2>::RetType;
  return [&] (T &&t, Cont<V> pass) {
    proc1(move(t), [&] (U &&u) {
      pipe(proc2, procs...)(move(u), pass);
    });
  };
}
```

So, what the hell?

Comment: What's the reason for declaring `auto proc2s` but not using it?

Comment: Sorry, that was just debug staff. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipe implementation has an undefined behavior. It captures everything by reference, so also pipe's function parameters, which are destroyed after pipe function ends. Either capture by copy [=], or pass to pipe by reference.

Comment: Awesome. It turns out that only `proc1` could be captured by reference because the construction of the lambda that calling `proc2` and `pass` is delayed. It's hard to transform my thoughts from languages that have GC. Thanks very much.

Comment: By the way, after hard trying, I have figure out how to write a CPS version of `pipe`, which is able to capture everything as references in all levels of lambda. Pretty fun!